# Anonymous class and outter private field

Tags: java, swing, field, inner-classes, anonymous-class

Is it legal to define a new anonymous class inside a method, and then assign an instance to an outer class private field, like commented in the code below? I am learning Java and trying to get my head around the reason behind this. Thanks!

```
public class Outer{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private SwingWorker doSomething; //Is it ok not to include it in the constructor?  
 public Outer (int id, String name){

    //constructor, but didn't include the instance doSomething
 }
 public void fuctionOne(){
    Swingworker doSomething =new SwingWorker<int, Void>(){
        protected int DoInBackground(){
          ...........// created an anonymous class and override methods
```

Comment: Did you try i? What does the compiler say?

Comment: "and then assign the instance of the anonymous class to a private field of the outer class" -> I can't see that you are doing this in your example. You are using a new local variable in "functionOne()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public void fuctionOne(){
    Swingworker doSomething = new SwingWorker<int, Void>(){
        protected int DoInBackground(){...
```

You are defining and initializing a local variable here, not assigning to the member of the `Outer` class.

If you want to initialize the `doSomething` member of `Outer`, do

```
 public void fuctionOne(){
    doSomething = new SwingWorker<int, Void>(){
        protected int DoInBackground(){...
```

In general, you don't have to initialize all the members of your class in the constructor. If you don't initialize them, they get default values (`null` in the case of reference types). You just have to make sure you initialize them before actually using them.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I didn't get the difference. What's the case for assigning it to the private field of Outer class?

Comment: @user4056620 As I wrote, it's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly legal. A couple of things to bear in mind, while you're thinking through these access rules:

1. As things stand, you've got a local variable `doSomething` that's shadowing your field instance, as noted by Eran. You need to avoid this, otherwise you won't be setting the field instance at all.
2. An inner class has access to everything that the outer class has, including its `private` methods and fields. Anything `private` is accessible only inside the class in which it's defined, but the point is that the inner class *is* inside the outer class.
3. An inner class can also access local variables defined outside of it (as long as they are in scope), but they must be declared `final`.

Comment: Thanks! so the way I am doing it is making doSomething a local variable. But for inner class like SwingWorker in this case, can it be a private class variable, as we might need to create an instance of Outer in some other class?

Comment: Yes, sure. You've got an instance field and a local variable in your code as it stands. Get rid of the local variable if you want it in an instance field.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule: if it compiles, it is allowed. And yes, assigning an anonymous class instance to a private field is allowed.

But in your code, you are not assigning anything to the field. You need to correct your code as follows

```
public class Outer{
  private SwingWorker doSomething;

  public void functionOne(){
    //SwingWorker doSomething = ...;//incorrect
    doSomething = ...;//correct
  }
}
```

If you want to make this more clear, you can always use

```
this.doSomething = ... ;
```

Although in general, your IDE indicate to you the difference between a local variable and a field by adjusting the text color.

Now the question is, is this a good thing to do.

- When you create the class, the value of the field is `null`
- You have a public method which assigns a value to the field, which can be called at any possible time. You have no control over when exactly the method will be called.
- You probably have another (public) method which will consume that field. This means that method either must be capable of dealing with `null` values, or instantiate the variable to a default value.

So you end up with a class having public methods which must be called in a certain order for the class to work correctly/as expected. This is typically not the best design option as it is very easy to forget about the ordering and accidentally call the methods in the wrong order.

Comment: Well explained. Plus the text color tip is really useful.